# Free SSL security certificate on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I pushed a [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) Rails app to Heroku and I see it's using ssl with`https://` and has a yellow padlock in the browser. Clicking on this shows "Identity verified" and the Certificate Information says Issued To: *.herokuapp.com

This is great. With no configuration or expense at the Heroku end, my app is using SSL with a valid looking certificate. Ok it's a yellow rather than green padlock but hey, not bad for free.

I'm sure this is a stupid question..but how can I run another Rails app on Heroku with a verified certificate without paying for the SSL add-on and purchasing my own certificate?

Comment: Now Heroku offers LetsEncrypt.org for free. They call it [automatic certificate management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management). It's only available with Hobby ($7/m) and up plans.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The TLS/SSL connection your browser is establishing is due to the fact the you are connecting to your app via appname.herokuapp.com. This is standard and will automatically work for any app you create out of the box. Heroku provides SSL encryption as you may be sending sensitive information to the server and it is better practice to encrypt data that you may not necessarily deem sensitive, but your client may. All reputable providers (SAS, Web Hosts, Email Providers) will have a `wildcard` SSL certificate installed to the base domain (*.herokuapp.com) as it is a single certificate that is relatively inexpensive and will secure all the sub-domains automatically.

That being said Apps are SSL-enabled already and can be accessed simply by using https, e.g., https://appname.herokuapp.com, but you would want to go with the SSL endpoint option when you want to establish the trusted relationship with your clients. Both ways are as secure as the other, but with the wildcard SSL (also referred to as a shared SSL certificate) the trust is established between the client via their browser and Heroku not your App/Site. With the SSL signed to your domain.com the clients can connect to your domain and not the Heroku sub-domain and see your site's information in the connection information on the browser. If your site is needing disambiguation from Heroku then is when you will want to proceed with an SSL setup outside the default.

As for what SSL type and issuer to use I would not recommend https://www.startssl.com/ as they do not offer SSLs with high browser ubiquity as they are not fully signed by an external root authority. Comodo and the consumer standard Rapid/GeoTrust are the best choices as far as assurance, recognition, and easy of use and concerned. You only need a DV (domain validated) SSL and they can be had for a few domains a month.

More on this and the Heroku SSL configuration can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint)

Comment: Thanks. I see the problem is that I was using my custom domain, which I realise needs its own cert, as only the *.herokuapp.com is covered by their cert. And setting config.force_ssl = true in production.rb uses https:// successfully for the hereokuapp.com address.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer 'Certificate don't match' is not a browser security warning I am familiar with so additional info may be needed, but that COULD mean that the SSL certificate installed to the browser does not match the address you are attempt to navigate to in the browser. The browser URI (myapp.heroku.com) mush match exactly to the CN 'common name' on the SSL certificate. I think this is the issue you are encountering.

Comment: ok then what should i do, i mean heroku supports ssl on all subdomains right. So why isn't mine working.?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer use https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html by entering the app.heroku.com URL and see what appears. That should provide you a good indication. If not I will need to have the app URL to troubleshoot.

Comment: hi, thanks for helping me out so far. I used that tool and everything was fine except: `None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered..Name mismatch Errors.`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer try https://v2ube.herokuapp.com instead of v2ube.heroku.com. You have to use the `herokuapp.com` url to use the SSL certificate they offer. :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently spent some time setting this up. It can be done using CloudFront and a proxy to Heroku. This is probably best used for small projects but seems to be working great so far! See my post here:

http://ksylvest.com/posts/2014-05-06/setup-free-ish-ssl-tls-on-heroku-for-ruby-on-rails-or-any-other-framework

Answer (score 1):

A few things have changed since this question was first answered, notably the advent of Let's Encrypt and new Heroku SSL endpoints, which together make it possible to add SSL for free. I've created a gem to generate and add certificates automatically: https://github.com/KMarshland/heroku-ssl. Once you've added heroku_ssl to your gemfile, you can simply run:

```
rake heroku_ssl:update_certs
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the gem, you can do these tasks manually:

**1. Generate the SSL Certificate**

Follow the instructions in https://github.com/unixcharles/acme-client  to generate your certificates. You'll need to register your email, authorize the domain, and then finally get your certificates. When authorizing the domain, if you only have one server running, you can simply stick the authorization file in your public folder; if not, you'll either have to set up a dedicated controller and route or add a text record to your DNS zone file.

**2. Add the certificate to Heroku**

After downloading your certificates, you can either use Heroku's web interface or just run

```
heroku certs:update fullchain.pem privkey.pem
```

**3. Configure your DNS**

You need to set a CNAME record in your DNS zone file that points to [yourdomain].herokudns.com. The DNS zone file specifies what urls get mapped to what servers on the domain name you own. If your site is already pointed to your Heroku app, there will already be a CNAME record; you just need to change where it points to. If not, you'll need to add a new line:

```
[subdomain] [TTL] IN CNAME [yourdomain].herokudns.com.
```

Comment: I recently used sslforfree.com on heroku with a custom domain for not cost, once you pay for a "Hobby" dyno